# XCode automatic code signing - Remove old app id

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle-identifier, apple-developer

Is it possible to remove a Bundle Identifier (or app ID) registered by XCode with automatic code signing?

We use XCode with automatic code signing for development.
For so long, our app did not need any Capabilities, but now we started to implement Push Notification, so this changed.
So we needed to change things with the certs, and now XCode shows this:

[image]

This is not the first time, we already had similar issues; and every time the solution was to change the Bundle ID, and then XCode's automatic code signing feature has done some magic in the background (I guess generated new certs or such for the new Bundle ID).
The current solution for the above issue is still this, so we change the Bundle ID.
Actually, we increment it (like com.myCompany.AppName --> com.myCompany.AppName.2 -> 3 -> 4 ...)
But this looks just silly.

Can one somewhere eliminate old Bundle IDs created by XCode automatic code signing?

Comment: Have you added the Push Notification capability in the entitlement file?

Comment: I did tick it in Xcode at the Capabilities tab. That's however not important now for the question, Push Notification is now only the context

Comment: The Provisioning Profile saying that the team doesn't support Push Notification and is required for the entitlement. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingLocalAndPushNotifications.html

Comment: Sorry, it is misleading, should have blured that part out, because it is not important for the question.
That problem is solved by incrementing the Bundle ID.
(The actual Bundle ID is bound to the wildcrad App ID on the pic, which can't have Push Notifications; that's why those error messages.)
The question is not about this problem however, this is only the context.